# SWI Prolog change working directory/get current working directory?

Tags: swi-prolog

in SWI Prolog terminal how do I view the current working directory and change the current working directory?

I found:

working_directory(CWD, CWD)

but I dont think its what I need

Comment: Why do you not think it's what you need?

Answer (score 29):

To get the current working directory use `working_directory(CWD, CWD)`.

To change the current working directory use `working_directory(_, NewCWD)`.

Check [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=working_directory/2) to see the manual entry for this predicate.

Comment: Tab completion is very handy in case directory names in the path contain space e.g. `working_directory(_, '/home/research/Artificial Intelligence/prolog').`

Comment: If using `working_directory/2` on Windows and the change will change both the drive and directory as opposed to same drive different directory, then you need to also call `working_directory/2` a second time with just the drive letter to change drives. e.g. You are on `C:\Users\Foo` and need to change to `D:\foo\bar` then you will need to use `working_directory/2` again just with the drive letter. `working_directory(_,"D:/")`.

Answer (score 5):

very easy just open prolog on terminal and write `working_directory(CWD,'NewPath')`.

Ex: `working_directory(CWD,'/home/user/prologExerc')`.

Answer (score 3):

To view the current directory use : `pwd`.

And to change it use : `working_directory(CWD,'path_or_location')`.

Example : `working_directory(CWD,'C:/Users/Student/Destop')`.

Remember to change the direction of slashes in the path name.